# Count number of positive columns from large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I have a large DataFrame with 500 columns out of which 300 columns `col1, col2, ..col300` appears as follows:

```
idx col1    col2
a   -1      4
b    2      1
c   -1     -1
```

I want to get the following for the 300 columns. Other 200 columns are variables I am not interested in:

```
idx col1    col2  numPos
a   -1      4     1
b    2      1     2
c   -1     -1     0
```

where for each row I want to get the number of positive values. I don't want to use the apply method as there are about 2 million rows in the DataFrame. Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select the columns + `gt` (which creates a boolean DataFrame where it's True if a value is positive) + `sum` on axis:

```
df['numPos'] = df[['col1','col2']].gt(0).sum(axis=1)
```

Maybe you could filter them too, like:

```
df['numPos'] = df.filter(like='col').gt(0).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  idx  col1  col2  numPos
0   a    -1     4       1
1   b     2     1       2
2   c    -1    -1       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way out is to exclude object columns, query what is greater than 0 in the df and sum along the row axis

```
  df['numPos']= df.select_dtypes(exclude='object').gt(0).sum(1)



  idx  col1  col2  status
0   a    -1     4       2
1   b     2     1       3
2   c    -1    -1       0
```

Answer (score 0):

`df['numPos'] = (df[cols] > 0).sum(axis=1)`
where cols is a list of column names. If the 300 columns are consecutive, then in place of `df[cols]` you can use `df.iloc[:,start_offset:start_offset+300]` where `start_offset` is the index of the first column.